# Additions to decaff coffee to complement taste

Tags: flavor, caffeine

I'm alternating drinking decaf bean coffee (O2 process) alongside caffeinated beans.

Normally I drink caffeinated either black or with a little milk.
With decaf, the reduced body of the taste is noticeable, and if I've drunk a few decafs I find the persisting aftertaste not ideal.

What additives do people add to decaf to complement its flavour, if any?

Answer (score 2):

It is complicated. You may try adding cream, milk, salt (for masking up the aftertaste), but I don't recall any barista adding any other stuff for improving the decaf taste.

You will hardly get it as good as a regular caffeinated coffee. The point is that the roasteries are often neglecting any improvements in their decaffeination process.

For me, what worked out was checking any local roasteries which would actually perform the method called "Swiss Water Process" for decaf. This one is quite ok for a lot of people, and if your local roastery is committed to doing it right, then it is all good.

Besides, have you tried any different brewing method?

Comment: Hi! Mainly been doing aeropress.

Comment: As a fan of aeropress, I'm not really sure what I could recommend you. You could try metal filters for improving the coffee body/flavors.. (Never tried w/ decaf, tbh).

Answer (score 1):

I've been fond of a heaping spoonful of cocoa powder - regular or Dutched - a small spoonful of sugar, and filling my mug with [soy]milk.